# problems when searching for certain substrings in a string

Tags: go

The code doesn't work properly.

I have to check all the substrings contained in the given string and they have to meet these two requirements:

- length at least equal to 3 characters;
- starting and ending with the same character.

The output has to include those substrings and their occurences.

No problems when giving in input ***abbabba*** and ***abcacba***, but when giving ***eabcacf*** errors start to pop-up. In fact it re-reads the ***cac*** substring and counts it another time, so I tried to fix this problem by checking where that substring is located (*strings.Index* function) and trimming the strings after, so if the substring needs to be re-read another time, it's for sure due to an occurency and not due to an error... at least this is what I thought.

...because when giving ***eabbcabcbf*** it re-reads ***cabc*** even after the previous fix, this is caused by the fact that ***cabc*** appears twice but not consecutively, so the *previous/current* approach doesn't work, it's necessarily needed a *previous2/previous1/current* approach to check also the third last substring, but I think that in this way, there will be always an error and fixing will result impossible.

Maybe the problem is caused by a possible wrong implementation of the code part that finds all the substrings at the beginning, but I can't figure it out how to fix it.

I attach the code and the outputs below.

Hope someone can help me!

**code**
(I put some *fmt.Println()* functions to print the slices and debug it)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    string1 := os.Args[1]
    count1 := 0
    count2 := 0
    count3 := 0
    var substring1, substring2, start1, previous1, output1 string
    var slice1, slice2, slice5 []string
    var slice3, slice4 []int
    var position1, saved1 int
    var check1 bool
    dict1 := make(map[string]int)
    for index1 := 3; index1 <= len(string1); index1++ {
        for index2 := 0; index2 <= len(string1)-3; index2++ {
            for _, value3 := range string1[index2:] {
                count1++
                substring1 += fmt.Sprintf("%s", string(value3))
                if count1 == index1 {
                    slice1 = append(slice1, substring1)
                    count1 = 0
                    substring1 = ""
                }
            }
            count1 = 0
            substring1 = ""
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(slice1)
    for _, value4 := range slice1 {
        substring2 = value4
        for index5, value5 := range substring2 {
            if index5 == 0 {
                start1 = string(value5)
            }
            if (index5 == len(substring2)-1) && (string(value5) == start1) {
                slice2 = append(slice2, substring2)
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(slice2)
    for index6, value6 := range slice2 {
        if index6 == 0 {
            previous1 = value6
        }
        if (value6 == previous1) && (index6 == 0) {
            position1 = strings.Index(string1[position1:], value6)
            saved1 = position1
            slice3 = append(slice3, position1)
        } else if (value6 == previous1) && (index6 != 0) {
            position1 = strings.Index(string1[saved1+1:], value6)
            slice3 = append(slice3, position1)
        } else if value6 != previous1 {
            position1 = 0
            position1 = strings.Index(string1[position1:], value6)
            saved1 = position1
            slice3 = append(slice3, position1)
        }
        previous1 = value6
    }
    fmt.Println(slice3)
    for index7, value7 := range slice3 {
        if value7 == -1 {
            slice4 = append(slice4, index7)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(slice4)
    if len(slice4) > 0 {
        for index8, value8 := range slice2 {
            for _, value9 := range slice4 {
                if index8 != value9 {
                    check1 = false
                } else {
                    check1 = true
                    break
                }
            }
            if check1 == false {
                slice5 = append(slice5, value8)
            }
        }
        fmt.Println(slice5)
        for _, value10 := range slice5 {
            dict1[value10] = dict1[value10] + 1
        }
        for range dict1 {
            count2++
        }
        for key1, item1 := range dict1 {
            count3++
            if count3 != count2 {
                output1 += fmt.Sprintf("%s -> Occorrenze: %d\n", key1, item1)
            } else {
                output1 += fmt.Sprintf("%s -> Occorrenze: %d", key1, item1)
            }
        }
        fmt.Println(output1)
    } else {
        for _, value8 := range slice2 {
            dict1[value8] = dict1[value8] + 1
        }
        for range dict1 {
            count2++
        }
        for key1, quantity1 := range dict1 {
            count3++
            if count3 != count2 {
                output1 += fmt.Sprintf("%s -> Occurrences: %d\n", key1, quantity1)
            } else {
                output1 += fmt.Sprintf("%s -> Occurrences: %d", key1, quantity1)
            }
        }
        fmt.Println(output1)
    }
}
```

**outputs**

*correct*

```
$ go run exercise_2.go abbabba
abbabba -> Occurrences: 1
bbabb -> Occurrences: 1
babb -> Occurrences: 1
abba -> Occurrences: 2
bbab -> Occurrences: 1
bab -> Occurrences: 1
```

*correct*

```
$ go run exercise_2.go abcacba
abcacba -> Occurrences: 1
bcacb -> Occurrences: 1
abca -> Occurrences: 1
acba -> Occurrences: 1
cac -> Occurrences: 1
```

*correct but actually incorrect due to bad approach*

```
$ go run exercise_2.go eabcacf
abca -> Occurrences: 1
cac -> Occurrences: 1
```

*incorrect*

```
$ go run exercise_2.go eabbcabcbf
bbcabcb -> Occurrences: 1
bcabcb -> Occurrences: 1
abbca -> Occurrences: 1
bbcab -> Occurrences: 1
cabc -> Occurrences: 2
bcab -> Occurrences: 1
bcb -> Occurrences: 1
```

⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: Had a quick look at your code but, without comments (and meaningful variable names), its difficult to work out what you are trying to accomplish with each step (splitting your code into functions would help too). I suspect your method is more complicated than necessary (but may have misunderstood the requirement); maybe consider something like [this](https://go.dev/play/p/MPuHVSXk1We) as a starting point.

Answer (score 3):

> check all the substrings contained in the given string and they have to meet these two requirements:
>
> • length at least equal to 3 characters;
>
> • starting and ending with the same character.
>
> The output has to include those substrings and their occurences.

Your solution is very complicated. Simplify.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func substrings(s string) map[string]int {
    ss := make(map[string]int)
    const k = 3 - 1
    for i := 0; i < len(s)-k; i++ {
        for j := i + k; j < len(s); j++ {
            if s[i] == s[j] {
                ss[s[i:j+1]]++
            }
        }
    }
    return ss
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(substrings("abbabba"))
    fmt.Println(substrings("abcacba"))
    fmt.Println(substrings("eabcacf"))
    fmt.Println(substrings("eabbcabcbf"))
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/hJMvMSYuqaa

```
map[abba:2 abbabba:1 bab:1 babb:1 bbab:1 bbabb:1]
map[abca:1 abcacba:1 acba:1 bcacb:1 cac:1]
map[abca:1 cac:1]
map[abbca:1 bbcab:1 bbcabcb:1 bcab:1 bcabcb:1 bcb:1 cabc:1]
```